# Azure Functions .NetCore 3.0 Request.Query throwing "Entry point not found" error

Tags: azure, .net-core-3.0

I have an Azure Functions project which builds and runs locally. One of my methods tries to access the HttpRequest.Query class to get parameters in the querystring which as of recently has started throwing errors including System.Private.CorLib: "Entry point not found" or

```
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Configurations_Get. 
BC.Functions: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IQueryCollection.get_Item(System.String)'.
```

The code of the function follows:

```
[FunctionName("Configurations_Get")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> GetConfigs(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route=ROUTE)]
        HttpRequest req,
        [Table("configurations", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] CloudTable configTable,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("Getting configuration");
        string version = "1.0";
        try
        {
            var query = req.Query;
            version = query["version"];
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            version = "1.0";
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

       ....
    }
```

Nuget versions as following

[image]
Any ideas on why this is happening? Is it a versioning issue?

Answer (score 0):

solved by removing unneeded references to

```
Microsoft.AspNetCode.Components.Browser
Microsoft.AspNetCode.Identity
Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms
```