# Azure Functions(.net core 3+) - Getting "Entry point was not found" error when trying to access HttpRequest.Query

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-core-3.0

I started encountering this issue about 3 days ago after an update that I randomly clicked on when I was in Visual Studio Code. Whenever I try to access HttpRequest.Query from the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http namespace, I get an the following error message: "Entry Point was not found".
[image]

[image]

I have not been unable to fix this and this has interrupted my ability to work. I've talked this over with my teammates, and they are not encountering this issue at all.

I've tried pretty much everything I could google and think of.

- Auto Generating Bindings
- Deleted and re installed every Nuget Package at C:\Users{username}.nuget\packages
- Deleting and reinstalling everything about Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code
- Using the most recent versions of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions
- Deleting the bin and obj folders of my project
- Removing unused references in my project

At this point, I'm not even sure what's really wrong any more. I found a post with my EXACT SAME issue, but the way the person fixed it did not apply to me:

[Azure Functions .NetCore 3.0 Request.Query throwing "Entry point not found" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56242212/azure-functions-netcore-3-0-request-query-throwing-entry-point-not-found-erro)

Some Info- may or may not be useful.

1. When I go through the code step by step in the debugger, HttpRequest.Query shows up properly with all of the keys. I'm wondering if there is some kind of name conflict between HttpRequest object from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http vs System.Web
2. If I set my project to use the most recent version of Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions, I get a new error instead of an entry point error, I get this instead:
   [image]
3. I'm using Visual studio Code.

Can anyone assist? I'd be happy to provide any information needed!

Comment: Can you show the code instead the screen shot?

Comment: Sorry, I gave up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up. I spent about 3 days trying to solve this and this was affecting my ability to work. I just had my entire laptop **reformatted** and that "fixed" the issue. I tried pretty much everything I could find and nothing worked and I couldn't wait any more. Best of luck to anyone who encounters this!

Comment: This makes me sad, i am facing this issue since last 7 days and I have tried everything. Whats the issue